# Package for drawing queue networks with LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, latex

Does anyone know how to draw queue network graphs that can be included within [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) documents?

Answer (score 5):

See, e.g., the following examples at [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) for the TikZ and PGF packages:

- [Graphs](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/)
- [Automata and Petri nets](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/)

Answer (score 3):

Use METAPOST for your problem.

Comment: If you have the time, patience and expertise, I would second this recommendation. It's not for the faint-hearted, but can produce extremely high-quality output.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to include drawings/graphs/images in your latex document.

The easiest way is just to draw the graph in your drawing program of choice, then export the graph to jpg or png (or eps if you're not using PDFlatex), then use the graphicx package ( \usepackage{graphicx} in your preamble), and include the graph in your document by using the code

```
\includegraphics[width=4in]{filename.jpg}
```

As indicated in other answers, there are several drawing languages that can be used with tex: metapost, tikz, and PGF are are powerful. There is also [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/), another code based drawing language.

You could also use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), which is excellent if your graph is large and you need graph something like network traffic. And [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) will turn your graphviz file into something latex can handle.

Comment: When using `pdftex`, you should prefer PDF graphics for vector images instead of PNG or JPG images.

Comment: Philipp -- probably true, but to really make a difference, it depends on the intended viewing medium-- print, screen, or other. Also, if you generate your jpeg or png with a sufficient pixel size, it probably won't matter.

A jpeg is easier for the lay user, as most people understand what a jpeg is and how to create one. However, throw the word "vector" around my office, and you're sure to end up with a lot of confused people. :D